# ToggleButton checked

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, togglebutton, checked, unchecked

I am working with Visual Studio 2013 in Windows store app.
I have a two ToggleButtons. 
They are working like switch:
I can check only one of them at a time.
When i check 1. toogle button then 2. toggle button unchecks.
When i check 2. toggle button then 1. toggle button unchecks.

My problem is when i check 1. toogle button and then click again 1. toogle button then it unchecks and then i have two unchecked toggle buttons.

**My question is:**
How to make the event that will know, when i clicked one toggle button that is already checked, it cannot be unchecked until i check the second toggle button. I need to disable the uncheked event for toggle button or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
togglebutton1_CheckedChanged(...)
{
    if(!togglebutton1.Checked && !togglebutton2.Checked)
        togglebutton1.Checked=True;
}
togglebutton2_CheckedChanged(...)
{
    if(!togglebutton2.Checked && !togglebutton1.Checked)
        togglebutton2.Checked=True;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A radio button may suit your needs better, but..

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
        checkBox2.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        checkBox2.Checked = false;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                checkBox2.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked != true)
            {
                checkBox2.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked != true)
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```